# How to set default for 'Unsubscribe Group' in civimail

Tags: civimail, angular

- Do a search using 'Find Contacts'
- Select a few and choose task 'Email - schedule/send via CiviMail'
- How do I set default value for *Unsubscribe Group*?

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way through the UI that I am aware of.

Comment: How can this be achieved through hooks?