# Not able to choose "unsubscribe group" for a mailing?

Tags: civimail, 4.7, unsubscribe

According to the [user guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/mass-mailings-using-civimail/#Choosing%20recipients:%20Groups%20versus%20search%20results), if I select contacts by search and then start a CiviMail mailing to them  I should be offered the "Unsubscribe group" option, as shown in this helpful screenshot posted on [another question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17608/how-to-set-default-for-unsubscribe-group-in-civimail).

[image: screenshot]

I can't get this to appear for the life of me. I'm on 4.7.27 under Wordpress. All I get is "Hidden Group 1234" in the Recipients field. Has this behaviour changed?

The reason for the question is that I want to do various searches to segment people but maintain a single unsubscribe group that would apply to any of my searches.

**EDIT** This might be a "please help me fix my CiviCRM install" question instead of a "how's it supposed to work" question.

On at least two of my installs (one Wordpress, one Drupal7) I don't see the Unsubscribe group option. Huh?

Reproduce: Search all contacts » Select some contacts » Mail by CiviMail.

Expect to see Unsubscribe Group option, but do not.

I agree with @petednz that this works on the 4.7/Drupal7 (actually 5.0.0 at time fo writing) demo site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug that was fixed in 4.7.28 [commit ref](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/4b0fb6ef332cfeb591221830f00c3fee11d6383e)

Doh!

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is exactly what I observe at dmaster.demo.civicrm.org.

Steps

Run Search and select some contacts.

Choose Email/Send via CiviMail

[image]

On the next screen I see the Unsub Group

[image]

Comment: The primary difference between this and normal CiviMails is AFAIK, the fact that the search creates a hidden group means that the unsubscribe isn't suitable to remove the person from that group so CiviCRM gives users the option to select another group as the Unsubscribe Group. Whereas in normal CiviMails it just uses the group the mailing is sent to as the unsubscribe group.

Comment: Hmmm. thanks. That's weird, I don't see that option on two of my sites. Have edited the question.

Comment: Yep weird - any other odd behaviours - anything in logs?